# How to install batsim simulator version 3.1.0

Tags: simulator, slurm, nix

i want to run simulations on batsim which is a SLURM simulator. there is a library called batsim-py which enables us to work with batsim through python. but batsim-py requires batsim version 3.1.0.
the newest batsim version is 4.2.0.
how to install the batsim version 3.1.0. the official installation guide uses nix and I am not understanding it. it provides some commands which installs batsim v4.1.0.
can anyone help me in installing batsim v3.1.0

i followed the installation instructions in https://batsim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installation

but they are for version 4.1.0

I want to install an older version (3.1.0)

How to install older version?

Answer (score 0):

The 3.1.0 version of Batsim is no longer available in the master branch. To access it, you need to pin an older branch such as `nixpkgs-22.11`. Here's an example of a `shell.nix` file that provides an environment with Batsim version 3.1.0 installed:

```hs
{
  kapack ?
    import
    (fetchTarball "https://github.com/oar-team/nur-kapack/archive/nixpkgs-22.11.tar.gz")
    {},
}:
kapack.pkgs.mkShell rec {
  name = "batsim-env";
  buildInputs = [
    kapack.batsim-310
  ];
}
```